# Javascript add function to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello there stackoverflow people, 
I'm messing around with HTML5 and Javascript and I'm trying to add a function to an object in javascript, just like a function is added to a class in C#.
Here is my javascript (I know this doesn't work)

```
function Hero()
{
    this.xPos = 100;
    this.yPos = 100;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "Images/Hero.png";
}

function MoveHero( xSpeed, ySpeed )
{
    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += ySpeed;
}
```

Now in my main loop function like so

```
function main()
{
    canvas.fillStyle = "#555555";
    canvas.fillRect( 0, 0, 500, 500);

    canvas.drawImage( hero.image, hero.xPos, hero.yPos );
    hero.MoveHero(1,1);
}
```

Now this ofcourse tells me that

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Hero> has no method 'MoveHero'"
```

How would I link the function so I could use

```
hero.MoveHero(x,y);
```

If anyone could help me out it would be awesome.

P.S. I am declaring my hero variable globally like so

```
var hero = new Hero();
```

is that ok?

Comment: `Hero.prototype.MoveHero=function(....)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can;

```
Hero.prototype.MoveHero = function( xSpeed, ySpeed )
{
    this.xPos += xSpeed;
    this.yPos += ySpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Hero()
{
    // add other properties

    this.MoveHero = function( xSpeed, ySpeed )
    {
        this.xPos += xSpeed;
        this.yPos += ySpeed;
    }
}
```